# Prove that $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}>\frac{1}{r}$ when you know that:

Tags: geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-inequalities

Let $ABC$ be a triangle.  Two points $P$ and $Q$ are on sides $AB$ and $AC$, respectively. The point $R$ is the intersection of lines $BQ$ and $CP$.  The distances from the points $P$, $Q$, and $R$ to the side $BC$ are $p$, $q$, and $r$, respectively. Prove that 
$$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}>\frac{1}{r}.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What are your thoughts on this question, and what have you tried so far? You can show your current work by clicking on the word "edit" in light grey just below your question. Showing us your current thoughts will help us better tune our answers to suit your understanding. *Not* showing us any effort will make us think that you just want us to do your homework for you, and that's not what this site is for.

Comment: Also, I think, that you deserve to know, that the tag [provability] is not about "anything that has to be proved" (if it were the case, all the questions here would have been bearing this tag), but rather about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provability_logic

Comment: Hint: Let $h$ be the altitude from $A$ of $\triangle ABC$.  Prove that $$\frac1p+\frac1q=\frac1r+\frac1h.$$

Comment: @Peter Dubecký I see a proof for acute angles $B$ and $C$. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.